# Scope of locally defined function in javaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this code snippet:

```
sayHi()

if (1) {
  function sayHi() {  alert(1)  }
} else {
  function sayHi() {  alert(2)  } // <--
}
```

How is it really working? The functions are defined in the if / else blocks. So how are they scoped outside the if / else blocks?

Comment: They aren't. When I run it, I get `TypeError: sayHi is not a function`

Comment: This question seems very unclear.........

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the function is the entire containing function, because function declarations are hoisted. But the function doesn't get its definition assigned to it until the `if` or `else` block is executed. It's equivalent to:

```
var sayHi;
sayHi();

if (1) {
    sayHi = function() { alert(1); };
} else {
    sayHi = function() { alert(2); };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is scoped at the function level in Javascript, not the block level as with most other languages. So if you define a `var` in a for loop, it is "hoisted" to the top of the containing function.

Comment: This is not completely true. `var` and `function` declarations are function scoped, but `let`, `const` and `class` declarations are block scoped.